# Compiling WxWidgets on Mac OSX 10.10

Tags: xcode, macos, wxwidgets, x86-64, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to compile WxWidgets 3.0.2 on my mac OSX 10.10
and I get the following message:

> Blockquote
>         ...
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make: *** [/Users/.../wxWidgets-3.0.2/build_rel/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau-3.0.0.2.0.dylib] Error 1

I'm compiling using these flags

> ../configure --with-osx_cocoa --with-macosx-version-min=10.7 --with-macosx-sdk=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk --prefix="$(pwd)" --with-opengl CC=clang CXX=clang++ CXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11" OBJCXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11" LDFLAGS=-stdlib=libc++ --enable-universal-binary=x86_64 --enable-monolithic --enable-unicode --with-expat=builtin --with-zlib=builtin --with-libtiff=builtin  --with-regex=builtin --with-libpng=builtin --with-libjpeg=builtin

As you can see I added the enable-universal-binary=x86_64 as suggested in other topics.

If you can suggest other flags that I might have not added or I should remove
that would be great..
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The other way:

```
brew install wxwidgets
```

you will get compiled wxWidgets in `/usr/local/Cellar`.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, this should work, but what is the point of using `--enable-universal-binary=x86_64`? It's not universal if there is only a single architecture... You probably wanted to use `--enable-macosx_arch=x86_64` instead.

BTW, I think the various stdlib-related options are unnecessary as well, clang is the default compiler under 10.10. And `--enable-unicode` is definitely superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

If you need wx3.0.0 osx 10.7+ monolitic, shared library can get it from here [wxphp stub bundle](https://yadi.sk/d/Oqk64Agjfc3rb)

Library is included in app/contents/resources , use it if you want. but you need headers c++, get it from wx side.

Answer (score 0):

As [posted here](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=40309%20%22here), you can use `--with-macosx-sdk=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/` as a workaround. There is an fixed [issue](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/16329) about it and will probably be released on 3.0.3.