# Configuring wxWidgets for OS X 10.10

Tags: xcode, wxwidgets, osx-yosemite

I am trying to build a program that relies on wxWidgets to run properly.  I have the latest version of Xcode installed.  I have tried building wxWidgets (both wxWidgets-3.0.2 and wxWidgets-2.9.4, the version originally used by the main program).  However, in both cases, running the makefile for the main program gives the following error:

make: /Users/***path to wxWidgets***/wxWidgets-2.9.4/build-cocoa-release/utils/wxrc/wxrc: No such file or directory

As I understand it, I need to build wxrc to get my main program to build properly (I have tried this, but apparently some header files are missing).  Is there any way to configure wxWidgets before this step that will automatically build wxrc as well?  Or is that something I need to build separately?  If it is separate, how would that be done?

I've pasted the code I originally used to configure wxWidgets below, with line breaks to make it easier to read:

```
../configure --with-osx_cocoa --with-macosx-version-min=10.7
--with-macosx-sdk=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk
--prefix="$(pwd)" --with-opengl CC=clang CXX=clang++ CXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11"
OBJCXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11" LDFLAGS=-stdlib=libc++
```

There is one error while building wxWidgets:
../src/osx/cocoa/utils.mm:250:28: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id' with an lvalue of type
      'wxNSAppController *'
        [NSApp setDelegate:appcontroller];

When I go into the samples directory and enter "make", I get: ld: library not found for -lwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-2.9 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) When entering "make" in demos, I get: ld: library not found for -lwx_osx_cocoau_core-2.9 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

If I missed any steps I should have taken before these (something with Xcode maybe?) please let me know.  Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: wxWidgets does build wxrc by default, if you get errors when building it, you should show them.

Comment: There are several warnings during building of version 2.9.4 (after using the above configuration and then entering "make"), but only one error: ../src/osx/cocoa/utils.mm:250:28: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id<NSFileManagerDelegate>' with an lvalue of type
      'wxNSAppController *'
        [NSApp setDelegate:appcontroller];

Comment: Not sure if this will be helpful, but when I go into the samples directory and enter "make", I get: ld: library not found for -lwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-2.9
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)  When entering "make" in demos, I get: ld: library not found for -lwx_osx_cocoau_core-2.9
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Please build 3.0.2, not some old development version. And, of course, you do need to build the library successfully first, before building anything using it, it's not really surprising `wxrc` can't be built if building the library failed...

Comment: I have tried both versions with the same results.  Which library are you referring to, and how would that be done?  I think I am probably missing something fairly obvious here.  Thanks again.

Comment: "The library" refers to wxWidgets itself: if you get an error building it (even if it's "only one" error), nothing can work. The trouble is that nobody else has reported the error you show in `utils.mm` so I'm not sure what's going on here. Which Xcode/SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 and the 10.10 sdk.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have Xcode 6.1 yet.

Comment: I'm trying with `Xcode 6.4`, with `MacOSX10.9` SDK, and voila, builds fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831360/compiling-wxwidgets-on-mac-osx-10-10/31117736). I have [sugested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31117736/845394) a workaround proposed on a forum as follows: you can use `--with-macosx-sdk=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/`".